# How to find a hidden program in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I want to access a datafile to retrive data from an app in my computer. The problem is that the location of the app itself is hidden and not visible in explorer. This is an app/program that I use so I know the app is there, somewhere.

Here is what I already tried:

- View hidden files is checked.
- Right clicking on the tile will not display option for locating app folder.
- View location folder in task manager is not enabled.
- Changing value in super hidden files in registry.

I’m lost…

Comment: Is it a Modern UI app? What type of data do you hope to access? It could always be stored in a proprietary format, making it useless without the program that created it.

Comment: Its a CRM software. Data from our customers, sales etc. Is what I was hoping to access. There is a couple of functions that is missing from the app. Its a modern app, maybe 5 years old.

Comment: You can be right about a proprietary format, but i wanted to check first. Right now I am a little frustrated that I cant even find the program.

Comment: I’m not talking about whether it’s modern as in recent. I’m talking about *Apps*. The ones you retrieve from Microsoft Store. // Locating the executable is pointless anyway. Unless it’s super crappy, it won’t store data within the installation directory but use established locations for user data (`%AppData%`) or all users data (`%ProgramData%`).

Answer (score 2):

If you know any folder name, just running a search from the start of the drive might help.

Alternatively, try finding the ***[%appdata%](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2690709/windows/whats-in-the-hidden-windows-appdata-folder-and-how-to-find-it-if-you-need-it.html)*** folder. It's a long shot, but it's also hidden and potentially includes what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To find a folder containing a program:

1. Start the app normally.
2. Right click on the little icon that appears on the taskbar (a little menu should open up).
3. Right click on the menu item with the name of the program.
4. Click on “properties” (a dialogue box will open).
5. The “shortcut” tab should be open, and the “target” field should be highlighted.  This is the path of the program executable.
6. Select only the path (the drive and folders part), without the .exe file, and without the quotations.  Right click and copy.
7. In File Explorer paste it into the search/path field at the top.  (Click on the little icon inside the search/path field at the left, and then right click to paste.)
8. The folder containing the executable file will open up.  The data file may or may not be in the same file, or a sub-folder.

Answer (score 1):

Open CMD Prompt and run attrib command wherever the file is located.

attrib -r -h -s

I noticed you showed hidden files, but you didn't activate to show System Files which the "-s" will remove that attribute so you can see it.

And to rehide them...

attrib +r +h +s

Answer (score 0):

If the app is somehow disguising itself as a system file, use the following procedure :

In Folder Options, in addition to choosing :
*Show hidden files, folders, and drives*,
uncheck also
*Hide protected operating system-files (Recommended)*.

Please note that such a behavior is likelier in a virus than in a legit app.
I would really suggest to uninstall it using a program such as
[Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html),
then running deep antivirus scans.